# SASS checking against a class name

Tags: css, class, variables, sass, mixins

Hi I'm still very new to SASS and no programming guru.

I have ten asides elements that all require different background colours based on their class name.

I've looked through the SASS documentation and I can't figure it out.

I want to say if aside has a class name of x make background colour x if aside has a class name of y make background colour y etc

Is there a nice efficient way of doing this?

Thanks guys and sorry if its a simpleton question.

Comment: You could loop over a list of lists... is there a reason you don't want to write out each definition?  Because setting up the looping is going to be just as much typing if the result is just a background-color definition for each class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using colors that don't have "standard" names (or the name of the class isn't going to be the name a color at all, eg. products = blue, addresses = red), a list of lists is what you want:

```
$colors:
    ( black #000
    , white #FFF
    , red #F00
    , green #0F0
    , blue #00F
    );

@each $i in $colors {
    aside.#{nth($i, 1)} {
        background: nth($i, 2);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
aside.black {
  background: black; }

aside.white {
  background: white; }

aside.red {
  background: red; }

aside.green {
  background: lime; }

aside.blue {
  background: blue; }
```

If you're using colors with standard keywords, this could work:

```
$colors2: black, white, red, green, blue;

@each $i in $colors2 {
    aside.#{$i} { background: $i; }
}
```

Output (though this only seems to work with `--style debug`, using `--style compress` generates errors.. weird):

```
aside.black {
  background: black; }

aside.white {
  background: white; }

aside.red {
  background: red; }

aside.green {
  background: green; }

aside.blue {
  background: blue; }
```

Comment: Thanks guys for all your help. Working a treat cheers. I'm using

Comment: To work around the errors using `--style compress`, you should make the color names that go into the selectors quoted strings. So, in the first example it would be: `$colors: ('black' #00F, 'white' #FFF, ...)`

Answer (score 0):

This is simply down to how much typing you want to do. You could make a background mixin and include it within the aside CSS rule, but is that really necessary?

If it is though....

```
@mixin bg($color) {
    background: $color;
}

aside#foo {
    @include bg(#fff);
}
```

Comment: FYI I don't think it is possible to do what you want exactly, but this is the closest SASS will get you!

Comment: Seriously why would you want to do this?

Answer (score -1):

"if aside has a class name of x make background colour x if aside has a class name of y make background colour y" translates to the following CSS:

```
aside.x {background-color: x}
aside.y {background-color: y}
```

Is there a reason you want to use SASS? Is it to make it dynamic so that you can add any class you want in the future without updating the CSS? (If so that's not possible with SASS because the SASS code compiles to CSS and doesn't change after).

To make that work you'd have to use JS (jQuery):

```
$('aside').each(function () {
    $(this).css('background-color', $(this).attr('class'));
});
```

Edit: You could use loops in SASS to generate a large number of classes and corresponding background-colors though.

Comment: You offered a solution for a question that wasn't asked.

Comment: Erm? Perhaps I misunderstood the question, but to me it seemed the OP wanted to give 10 elements different bg-colors based on their class names. I offered a CSS solution (just writing the CSS like normal) and a JS solution to that problem/question. Which question do you think I answered that wasn't asked?